# Create backup folder with several directories and files

Tags: vbscript

I am new at this and I am trying to get a VBScript (Because the aplicattion only works with this) tha makes a backup of several directories and files...

EXample:

```
Check if Folder1 exist... (It may be on c:\ or another drive)
If don´t exist the finish
If exist than should create a Bck Folder
THan Backup the folders that are inside folder1 (Folder2, Folder3)
Also backup all the files that are *.mds, *.vbs inside Folder4
The script have to maintain the struture...
And after that delete all folder1
```

This is what I have so far:

```
IF NOT EXIST "%INSTALLDIR%\Folder1\" GOTO ENDPROG 
mkdir "%INSTALLDIR%\BCK\" 
mkdir "%INSTALLDIR%\BCK\DADOS\" 
mkdir "%INSTALLDIR%\BCK\IMAGEM\" 
mkdir "%INSTALLDIR%\BCK\CONFIG\" 
mkdir "%INSTALLDIR%\BCK\OFFBck" 
copy "%INSTALLDIR%\Folder1\Dados*.MDB" "%INSTALLDIR%\BCK\dados\" 
copy "%INSTALLDIR%\Folder1\Dados*.MDD" "%INSTALLDIR%\BCK\dados\" 
copy "%INSTALLDIR%\Folder1\Dados*.VEI" "%INSTALLDIR%\BCK\dados\" 
copy "%INSTALLDIR%\Folder1\Imagem*.*" "%INSTALLDIR%\BCK\Imagem\" 
copy "%INSTALLDIR%\Folder1*.cfg" "%INSTALLDIR%\BCK\Config\" 
copy "%INSTALLDIR%\Folder1\OFFbck*.ZIP" "%INSTALLDIR%\BCK\OFFbck\" 
copy "%INSTALLDIR%\Folder1\Folder1\OFFbck*.ZIP" "%INSTALLDIR%\BCK\OFFbck\" 
rmdir "%INSTALLDIR%\Folder1" /s /q 
:ENDPROG
```

Can anyone give me a hand on this?

I already did this.....But i give an error if the folder already exist for the backup....but I cannot start to copy....

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objFSO.FolderExists("C:\Folder1") Then
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Const OverwriteExisting = TRUE
    Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder("C:\BCK")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder("C:\BCK\Imagem")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder("C:\BCK\dados")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder("C:\BCK\config")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder("C:\BCK\off")
Else
End If
```

Thanks in advance

I just created this....

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objFSO.FolderExists("C:\audatex") Then
    Const OverwriteExisting = True
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder("C:\BCK")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder("C:\BCK\Imagem")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder("C:\BCK\dados")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder("C:\BCK\WTB")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder("C:\BCK\CFG")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder("C:\BCK\config")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder("C:\BCK\offdaten")
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    objFSO.CopyFile "C:\Audatex\offdaten\*.zip" , "c:\BCK\Offdaten\" , OverwriteExisting
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    objFSO.CopyFile "C:\Audatex\Dados\*.vei" , "c:\BCK\dados\" , OverwriteExisting
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    objFSO.CopyFile "C:\Audatex\Dados\*.mdd" , "c:\BCK\dados\" , OverwriteExisting
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    objFSO.CopyFile "C:\Audatex\*.cfg" , "c:\BCK\CFG\" , OverwriteExisting
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    objFSO.CopyFile "C:\Audatex\Dados\*.mdb" , "c:\BCK\dados\" , OverwriteExisting
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    objFSO.CopyFolder "C:\Audatex\Imagem" , "c:\BCK\Imagem" , OverwriteExisting
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    objFSO.CopyFile "C:\Audatex\WTB\*.wtb" , "c:\BCK\WTB\" , OverwriteExisting
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    objFSO.CopyFile "C:\Audatex\WTB\*.dtb" , "c:\BCK\WTB\" , OverwriteExisting
End IF
```

But know I have the following problems: If there is nothing on the folders i got an error and i cannot overwrite the folders

Thanks

Comment: I tried and I made a vbscritp to call a batch but I need to have everything inside the vbscript....I don´t really understand the vbscript language...and this is for a simple working installation

Comment: Show us what you've tried and then we can help you make it work.

Comment: Please do not post code in comments. Edit your question instead. Also, what you have is batch code, not VBScript code. Encapsulating batch code in VBScript is possible (using the [`Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) or [`Exec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method), but I would't advise it for the task you described. Either stick with batch, or re-implement it in proper VBScript.

Comment: What i really need is this in vbscript code...but has I told before...I never did anything in vbscript....

Comment: First: stop (re-)creating `objFSO` over and over again. Create it once and then leave it alone. As for the error, if your problem is that the script terminates with an error when `CopyFile` doesn't find matching file, you could put the copy instructions between `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error Goto 0`. Note that this will mask all errors. If you need to detect error conditions other than "no such file" you need to add error handling code. Otherwise you can use a loop as described in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy files with particular extensions that start with a specific string like this:

```
For Each f In objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Folder1").Files
  ext = LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(f))
  If (ext = "mdb" Or ext = "mdd" Or ext = "vei") And LCase(Left(f.Name, 5)) = "dados" Then
    f.Copy "C:\BCK\dados\"
  End If
Next
```

Another (perhaps simpler) option would be to check the file name with a regular expression:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^dados.*\.(mdb|mdd|vei)$"
re.IgnoreCase = True

For Each f In objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Folder1").Files
  If re.Test(f.Name) Then f.Copy "C:\BCK\dados\"
Next
```